# Adding "note" to the products in woocommerce for admins

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to add custom "note" to each product, for the product type "Variable Product", that's only visible for backend users admins, and not for the public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User **Advanced Custom Fields** https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ plugin and create the field group with Note field and assign to Product post_type only .

It will displayed admin side only until you don't code for front side.